# How to change the sysdate format in eclipse for queries?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yy");
String date = df.format(today);
System.out.println(date);
PreparedStatement sql = con.prepareStatement("select count(*), name, status from tablename where file_date = date group by name, status");
ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery();
However, the sysdate format in SQL is dd/MM/yy
```

But the date format in Eclipse is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`

How do I convert it in query so that I can get `dd/MM/yy` format?

Comment: A date has not format in Java.

Comment: @Tom I formatted it at Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yy");
String date = df.format(today);
System.out.println(date);
is it ok?

Comment: @Abdelhak it is not wkring and showing invalid expression error

Comment: This `String date` is a formatted representation of the unformatted Date `today`. When you're working with databases, then you shouldn't persist Strings for dates. Use `java.sql.Date` instead.

Comment: @Tom how do i do it? i tried the sql.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())); im still getting no results.

Comment: When Bergers solution doesn't work for you, then you should ask him about that, before you accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

What about passing a true SQL Date, don't bother about internal string representation for dates.

```
PreparedStatement sql = con.prepareStatement("select count(*), name, status from tablename where file_date = ? group by file_name, status");

sql.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
```